# How to properly use Task.Factory.StartNew and .ContinueWith

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Task Factory that starts a Task that consumes REST.

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncUser(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t1) => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncSystemSerial(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t2) => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncContacts(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t3) => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncRetailerOutlet(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t4) => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncCAF(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t5) => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncCAFActivity(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t6) => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncEmailRecipient(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t7) => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncProvince(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t8) => await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncTown(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus))
 .ContinueWith(async (t9) => await App.TodoManager.SyncUserLogsClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus));
```

I am having 4 problems:
1. Not all of the Task is being executed meaning it only executes the function from FirstTimeSyncUser until FirstTimeSyncTown. The last Task wont execute.
2. Sometimes the execution of the Tasks Overlaps meaning 2 or more Task are being executed instead of one at a time. 
3. The error message from each Task is not showing when there is an exception error meaning each of the Task have a try-catch system when there is an error or exception it should display a Message box or DisplayAlert to notify the use what the error is. (The sample is below)
4. I am alway getting a SQLite.SQLiteException: Busy or SQLite.SQLiteException: Database Locked.

Here is the sample:

```
public async Task FirstTimeSyncTown(string host, string database, string domain, string contact, Action<string>SyncStatus)
    {
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            string apifile = "first-time-sync-town-api.php";
            int count = 0;

            var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://" + domain + "/TBSApi/" + apifile + "?Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database, string.Empty));

            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                    {
                        var dataresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TownData>>(content, settings);
                        var datacount = dataresult.Count;

                        for (int i = 0; i < datacount; i++)
                        {
                            SyncStatus("Syncing town " + (count + 1) + " out of " + datacount);

                            var item = dataresult[i];
                            var townID = item.TownID;
                            var provinceID = item.ProvinceID;
                            var town = item.Town;
                            var lastsync = DateTime.Parse(current_datetime);
                            var lastupdated = item.LastUpdated;
                            var deleted = item.Deleted;

                            var insertdata = new TownTable
                            {
                                TownID = townID,
                                ProvinceID = provinceID,
                                Town = town,
                                LastSync = lastsync,
                                LastUpdated = lastupdated,
                                Deleted = deleted
                            };

                            await conn.InsertOrReplaceAsync(insertdata);

                            count++;
                        }

                        //synccount += "Total synced town: " + (count + 1) + "\n";

                        var logType = "App Log";
                        var log = "Initialized first-time sync (<b>Town</b>)  <br/>" + "App Version: <b>" + Constants.appversion + "</b><br/> Device ID: <b>" + Constants.deviceID + "</b>";
                        int logdeleted = 0;

                        await Save_Logs(contact, logType, log, database, logdeleted);

                        Preferences.Set("townchangelastcheck", current_datetime, "private_prefs");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("First-time Town Sync Error", "Syncing failed. Status Code:\n\n" + response.StatusCode, "Yes", "No");

                    if (retry.Equals(true))
                    {
                        await FirstTimeSyncTown(host, database, domain, contact, SyncStatus);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        First_Time_OnSyncFailed();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("First-time Town Sync Error", "Syncing failed.\n\n Error:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Yes", "No");

                if (retry.Equals(true))
                {
                    await FirstTimeSyncTown(host, database, domain, contact, SyncStatus);
                }
                else
                {
                    First_Time_OnSyncFailed();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("First-time Town Sync Error", "Syncing failed. Please connect to the internet to sync your data. Do you want to retry?", "Yes", "No");

            if (retry.Equals(true))
            {
                await FirstTimeSyncTown(host, database, domain, contact, SyncStatus);
            }
            else
            {
                First_Time_OnSyncFailed();
            }
        }
    }
```

The purpose why I use Task.Factory is to sequence the Task execution. Is there a better way to execute the task one by one meaning the other Tasks wont execute unless the current Task is finished executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` and `ContinueWith` are both very low-level methods that should generally be avoided. In particular, they do not understand `async` delegates; this is why you're seeing overlapped execution.

> The purpose why I use Task.Factory is to sequence the Task execution. Is there a better way to execute the task one by one meaning the other Tasks wont execute unless the current Task is finished executing?

Yes. You should use `async` and `await`.

```
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncUser(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncSystemSerial(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncContacts(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncRetailerOutlet(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncCAF(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncCAFActivity(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncEmailRecipient(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncProvince(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncTown(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncUserLogsClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
```

Comment: is the code that I provided can cause SQLite.SQLiteException: Busy or SQLite.SQLiteException: Database Locked?

Comment: is the code that I provided can cause SQLite.SQLiteException: Busy or SQLite.SQLiteException: Database Locked?

Comment: Possibly, because of the overlapped execution.

Comment: so this will fix the overlapped execution?

Comment: Yes, `await` means "asynchronously wait", so it ensures they are only run one at a time.

Comment: so how about when for example in my code there  is a chance that you can retry when you encountered an exception error will that overlap with the other Task? See my code to see what I mean

Comment: `await FirstTimeSyncTown(..)` will asynchronously wait until `FirstTimeSyncTown` returns or an exception propagates out of `FirstTimeSyncTown`. It doesn't matter if `FirstTimeSyncTown` just does one API call, or retries 100 times, or awaits until a user presses a button, or anything. `await FirstTimeSyncTown(..)` will asynchronously wait until that method returns a result or throws an exception.

Comment: so just to be clear when I choose to retry a Task it will not overlap with the other Task correct? I just want to be sure

Comment: `await` will pause until `FirstTimeSyncTown` returns or throws. `FirstTimeSyncTown` can do whatever it wants, including retries, and the `await` will (asynchronously) wait for it.

Comment: I have a another question how can I prevent await from executing when the current Task failed?

Comment: If you want to catch the exception, the most natural approach is to do a `try { await ... } catch { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

If all your methods are async and all you want to do is have them run in order, why do you need to use Task.Factory? Can you not just await them in order like so:

```
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncUser(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus));
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncSystemSerial(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus));
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncContacts(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus));
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncRetailerOutlet(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus));
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncCAF(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus));
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncCAFActivity(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus));
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncEmailRecipient(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus));
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncProvince(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.FirstTimeSyncTown(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncUserLogsClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
```

Comment: so to clarify, when I use await it will not execute the next Task if the current task is still being executed?

Comment: Yes, await pauses execution until the async method has completed.

Comment: Even if I chose to retry a Task when I have a exception? see my code to know what I am talking about

Comment: I have a question. It is great that this method works my problem now is How can I prevent other Task from executing when the I chose not to Retry?